# Loading txt file into verilog testbench

Tags: memory, loading, verilog

I would like to load a few data from .txt file into the testbench as input in order to run the simulation, but the data I wish to load in are real numbers.

For example:

```
 0.00537667139546100
 0.0182905843325460
-0.0218392122072903
 0.00794853052089004
```

I found that `$readmemh`, or `$readmemb` are meant for hex or binary. Is there any method that can help me to load the data without convert it to binary or hex before loading it to the testbench?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$readmemh` and `$readmemb` are meant to load data into memory. As you mentioned, these functions requires hex or binary data. If you simply want to use some data read from file, you can use `$fscanf` function with `%f` format set, i.e.:

```
$fscanf(file,"%f ",real_num);
```

Comment: sorry can you be more specific? I having error when implementing the code above. By the way how to name the file? Do I need to load the file into the library?

Comment: What kind of error? First of all, you need to open a file with `$fopen()` function. This way you get a pointer to the file.